# How to get coordinates and brightness of all stars from 1 constellation on SIMBAD?

Tags: coordinate, data-analysis, simbad

I would like to get the RA and DEC coordinates and brightness data of all stars in the Orion constellation from SIMBAD. I am attempting to do a 'criteria query' but I'm confused about how to sort the database by constellation. Please help.

Comment: You could use Orion's constellation boundaries, but you'd have to precess them from B1850 when they were defined. I don't see an easy solution here. Maybe get the stars for Orion's bounding box and then cull manually? (ie, with a script after download)

Comment: While not a solution using SIMBAD, there's a [list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stars_in_Orion) which can be sorted by magnitude

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's every star in Orion but entering `* Ori` in the identifier box on SIMBAD and setting the *you can choose to query :* to the `with wildcards` option as shown in the screen shot below
[image: SIMBAD website showing the query for all stars in the Orion constellation]
returns 2914 stars with the RA, Dec and magnitudes (although the query does take a while to execute...) You can change what columns are returned in the result or the output file type (if the default HTML table is less useful for future uses) by clicking on that yellow backgrounded *Output options* tab first (remember to save changes via the 'SAVE' button at the bottom of the form)

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't get stars like `2MASS J22472789+5807236` (which may or may not be in Orion) that don't include the constellation name in the identifier.

Comment: This is true. I'm making the assumption that the OP is primarily interested in the brighter more obvious stars but this may not be true. There are ways to [query a region](http://simbad.cds.unistra.fr/guide/sim-fsam.htx#Sregion) so with additional effort you could define a polygon for the Orion constellation and query within that region of the sky.